# Access is denied option and build was failure when running the jenkins due to git tool is none: What does that mean?

Tags: github, jenkins, playwright

Started by user Umer Ejaz
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\data\jenkins_home\workspace\Playwright_series
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\Users\Omer.Ejaz\LocalGitRepo.git # timeout=10
> Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/umerTechQa/Playwright.com # timeout=10
> Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/umerTechQa/Playwright.com
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
> git --version # 'git version 2.42.0.windows.2'
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/umerTechQa/Playwright.com +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit}" # timeout=10
> Checking out Revision 4ece2e8581f46fc423995afb53f8b00805b62674 (refs/remotes/origin/main)
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 4ece2e8581f46fc423995afb53f8b00805b62674 # timeout=10
> Commit message: "updated"
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk 4ece2e8581f46fc423995afb53f8b00805b62674 # timeout=10
> Parsing POMs
> ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
> hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective settings
> [FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin (Access is denied) @ C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin
> [FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin (Access is denied) @ C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin

```
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:129)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:110)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:137)
at hudson.maven.MavenUtil.createEmbedder(MavenUtil.java:211)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1324)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1124)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1198)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1181)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:985)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:689)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```

Caused by: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin (Access is denied) @ C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin
[FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin (Access is denied) @ C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin

```
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:262)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:159)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:121)
... 14 more
```

Caused by: org.apache.maven.settings.building.SettingsBuildingException: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin (Access is denied) @ C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin
[FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin (Access is denied) @ C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\Java\apache-maven-3.9.4\bin

```
at org.apache.maven.settings.building.DefaultSettingsBuilder.build(DefaultSettingsBuilder.java:129)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:260)
... 16 more
```

[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level C:\Users\Omer.Ejaz\jenkins_report to C:\Program Files\Jenkins\data\jenkins_home\jobs\Playwright_series\htmlreports\HTML_20Report
ERROR: Directory 'C:\Users\Omer.Ejaz\jenkins_report' exists but failed copying to 'C:\Program Files\Jenkins\data\jenkins_home\jobs\Playwright_series\htmlreports\HTML_20Report'.
Finished: FAILURE
REST API
Jenkins 2.414.3